# Python3: Syntax error when 'if' is used before the for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm getting a syntax error when `if` is used before the `for` loop without an `else`, but no such error when `else` is present.

Here is my code:

```
data=[[45, 12],[55,21],[19, -2],[104, 20]]
retData= ['Close' if i>54 and j>7 for [i,j] in data]
# getting a syntax error here :(
return retData
```

The code below works, which has `if` and `else` prior to the `for` loop.

```
data=[[45, 12],[55,21],[19, -2],[104, 20]]
retData= ['Close' if i>54 and j>7 else 'Open' for [i,j] in data]
# No Syntax error here!!
return retData
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen in the first case? Do you want to exclude items from the list if the condition is not satisfied? In this case you should use the syntax `[something(v) for v in data if condition(v)]`.

Comment: Yes, if the condition is not satisfied the items from the list should be excluded, but the question remains that why does the syntax `[something(v) if condition(v) else somethingElse(v) for v in data ]` works perfectly fine, but the syntax  `[something(v) if condition(v)) for v in data ]` gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oups, there is a confusion between the Python syntax for the ternary operator:

```
expression_if_true if condition else expression_if_false
```

and the conditional list comprehension

```
[ expression for elt in list if condition ]
```

The second code is an unconditional list comprehension (no `if` after the `for`) where the expression contains a ternary operator.

In first code, you have no else condition, so you must use a conditional list comprehension, where the if *acts* on the for and is placed after if:

```
retData= ['Close' for [i,j] in data if i>54 and j>7]
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are looking for is.

```
data=[[45, 12],[55,21],[19, -2],[104, 20]]
retData= ['Close'  for [i,j] in data if i>54 and j>7]
```

if it is only `if` condition in list comprehension then it should come after the loop syntax.